# VS.Php support for Magento Development in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: php, visual-studio-2010, magento

Can anybody please comment as whether the [VS.Php IDE](http://www.jcxsoftware.com/) will help in all those ways which the "[NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/)" / "Eclipse" / "Zend Studio" IDEs provide, for the Magento development?

The features for which I'm asking are like:-

- Using the NetBeans SOAP API Web Services of the Magento V2 SOAP API.
- Understanding the IntelliSense of the Parent Class & showing the properties & methods of the Parent Class. This helps in maintaining the abstraction of the project.
- Using the Magento debugging techniques.
- ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into [PhpStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) by [JetBrains](http://www.jetbrains.com/index.html), but choose Eclipse or Zend Studio if you might need remote editing, as all other IDEs fail in this part miserably.